# Smallest degree of approximating polynomial

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, polynomials, approximation-theory, interpolation

Let $\{0,1\}^n=S_0\cup S_1$ withh $S_0\cap S_1=\emptyset$.

Let $\epsilon\in[\frac{1}2,1)$.

Let $f:\Bbb R^n\rightarrow\Bbb R$ be a polynomial such that $$f(S_0)=0,\mbox{ }f(S_1)\subseteq[1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]\quad\quad (f(S_1) \mbox{ lies in interval } [1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]\mbox{ and is considered non-constant in } [1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon])$$

I want to find an univariate polynomial $h:\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ such that $h\circ f:\Bbb R^n\rightarrow\Bbb R$ satisfies $$h(f(S_0))=0,\mbox{ }h(f(S_1))\subseteq\Big[1,\Big(\frac{1+\epsilon}{3\epsilon-1}\Big)^2\Big]$$

What degree of $h$ suffices for this purpose?

Is this roughly $\frac{1+2\epsilon-\epsilon}{\Big(\frac{1+\epsilon}{3\epsilon-1}\Big)^2-1}=\frac{1+\epsilon}{\Big(\frac{1+\epsilon}{3\epsilon-1}\Big)^2-1}$ which is unbounded if $\epsilon\rightarrow1$?

---

Conversely, let $f:\Bbb R^n\rightarrow\Bbb R$ be a polynomial such that $$f(S_0)=0,\mbox{ }f(S_1)\subseteq\Big[1,\Big(\frac{1+\epsilon}{3\epsilon-1}\Big)^2\Big]$$

I want to find an univariate polynomial $h:\Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ such that $h\circ f:\Bbb R^n\rightarrow\Bbb R$ satisfies $$h(f(S_0))=0,\mbox{ }h(f(S_1))\subseteq[1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon]$$

What degree of $h$ suffices for this purpose?

Is this roughly $\frac{\Big(\frac{1+\epsilon}{3\epsilon-1}\Big)^2-1}{1+2\epsilon-\epsilon}=\frac{\Big(\frac{1+\epsilon}{3\epsilon-1}\Big)^2-1}{1+\epsilon}=O(1)$ if $\epsilon\in(\frac{1}2,1)$?

---

Is my degree estimates right?

Comment: This is asked in a peculiar way. When you say $f(S_1)\in [1,1+2\epsilon]$, do you mean $f(S_1)\subset[1,1+2\epsilon]$ or that $f$ is constant on $S_1$ and its value lies in the interval?

Comment: @MichaelRenardy "lies in interval and is non-constant taking values in interval".

Comment: It's a bit odd to see $\epsilon \in [1/2,1)$, too. Usually one uses $\epsilon$ to denote a small positive number where one might be interested in the behavior as $\epsilon \to 0$. Why not use $\epsilon' = 1-\epsilon$?

Answer (score 1):

These kinds of questions come up a lot in Theoretical Computer Science.  Tools for upper bounds include constructions based on Chebyshev polynomials and Jackson's Theorem; tools for lower bounds include Remez-type inequalities.  See, e.g., these papers for several examples of the tricks one can use:

http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~rocco/Public/bifh-final.pdf
http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~rocco/Public/combinatorica.pdf
http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~rocco/Public/stoc01.pdf

Comment: Thank you. I am not familiar with analysis theorems since I have never dealth with this kind of degree statements. First look at some of approximation books gives me some degree of uncomfort. Is my crude estimate correct?

Comment: which theorems are you referring in the papers? Do my estimates make sense?